# How to comput the different set by Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have two files like below.

for file A

```
AA
BB
CC
DD
EE
FF
```

for file B

```
BB
CC
DD
UU
VV
```

My job is to find those words which appear in file B, but not in file A. You can regard file B is only a file, but file A is a bunch of files.

Below is what I am doing.

For Map phase:

```
emit(word,filename)
```

For Reduce phase:

check the word,

```
if COUNT(values)>1:
   ignore it. 
if COUNT(values)==1 and filename != A:
   ignore it.
emit(word)
```

Do you have any better solution?

**UPDATE**

There is no duplicate entry in one file.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your solution .

```
if COUNT(values)>1:
   ignore it. 
for file A

AA
BB
CC
DD
EE
FF
for file B

BB
CC
DD
UU
VV
VV
```

so VV will not feature in the ans which is wrong .

---

(change) Ans :

Reduce :

```
 if(value.contains(FileName A) && value.contains(FileName B))
  ignore;
else if (value.contains(FileName A) && !value.contains(FileName B))
 ignore;
 else 
emit(key)
```

---

Comment: There is a policy in those file which there is no duplidate entry in one file. Which means your file B is invalidate

Comment: Ok .As it was not mentioned in qus , so i ansed it for generic Files